# Filter date with intervals of 1 hour between two random dates in the same day

Tags: sql, oracle

**The rule**

Any records between one hour should be counted as one.

**Data**

```
ID     DATE

1      06/07/2017 09:20:35
2      06/07/2017 10:20:35
3      06/07/2017 10:25:30
4      06/07/2017 10:40:35
5      06/07/2017 10:50:35
6      06/07/2017 11:25:30
7      06/07/2017 11:50:20
8      06/07/2017 15:25:30
9      06/07/2017 17:25:30
10     06/07/2017 17:30:30
11     06/07/2017 17:40:55
```

**Expected result**

```
count       date

5           06/07/2017
```

Why? Based on the minimum date, the records between one hour after are counted as one. Something like this:

```
count       range_date

1           09:20:35 - 10:20:35
1           10:20:36 - 11:20:36
1           11:20:37 - 12:20:37
0           12:20:38 - 13:20:38
0           13:20:39 - 14:20:39
0           14:20:40 - 15:20:40
1           15:20:41 - 16:20:41
1           17:20:42 - 18:20:42
```

Any suggestions to do so?
Something in one statment since I don't have a rule for the dates (min/max). I just know that all dates it's on the same day.

And I dont want to make N selects between every hour...

Comment: Not clear what you are counting. Which intervals have AT LEAST one row in the input table? Also: Your definition of "time_range" (not clear why it is called "**date**_range" since all times are on the same date) doesn't make sense. One hour intervals should be from 9:20:35 to 10:20:34, then from 10:20:35 to 11:20:34 etc.

Comment: That's how it is... one "range" (aka interval) is between 09:20:35 to 10:20:35. another one: 10:20:36 to 11:20:36. I'm count everything between one hour above the minimum date until the max one...

Comment: I think last row of your example must be 18:20:42 instead of 18:20:41

Comment: Why would you want the intervals to be 3,601 seconds long?  (Especially when the title suggests exactly one hour.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your problem, this is a query that obtain the result you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
    TRUNC(dt) AS day, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT TRUNC(dt - 20 / (24 * 60) - (35 + TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(dt, 'HH24')) - 9) / (24 * 60 * 60), 'HH24')) AS hours
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY TRUNC(dt)
```

- `TRUNC(dt, 'HH24')` truncates the date to hour (minutes and seconds
  are set to 0)
- I subtract the minutes and seconds of starting hour to
  "shift" the `TRUNC` to correct time period
- `TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(dt, 'HH24')) - 9)` is mandatory to add one second for every hour
- With `COUNT DISTINCT` you
  count the number of different hours.
- If the initial hour is variable (as I suppose) I think the easiest way is to keep it with separate query, extract hour, minute and second and use them as variables in input to the main query

Comment: This looks correct, but overly complicated. Gordon's solution is simpler and in the same spirit. It just needs to use (dt - min_dt) * 3601/86400 to account for the extra second every hour, instead of (dt - min_dt)/24.

Answer (score 0):

You want to count the number of hours since the earliest date/time for each record.  Here is one approach:

```
select trunc(dt), count(distinct trunc((dt - min_dt) / 24)) as num_hours
from (select t.*, min(dt) over (partition by trunc(dt) order by dt) as min_dt
      from t
     ) t
group by trunc(dt);
```

This expression `(dt - min_dt) / 24` calculates the time between each date/time and the earlier in hours.  the `count(distinct)` counts the number of distinct hours seen in the date.

Comment: I think this query keeps same value of second for all time intervals, but in the example seconds increase: every interval is exatly one hour an one second long

Comment: It can be easily fixed though. In the solution (dt - min_dt) is multiplied by 1/24 to transform from "days" to "hours" (in Oracle date/time arithmetic, 1 is one day). To check for integral multiples of one hour and one second instead of exactly one hour, (dt - min_dt) should be multiplied by 3601/86400. (Note that one hour is 3600 seconds and one day is 86400 seconds.)